# PHP curl with current session

Tags: php, session, curl, cookies

i had a php api running and want to place a subrequest to an other endpoint of it with curl, but run into some trubble.

```
$ch = curl_init($this->url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//execute with cookie session
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, session_name().'='.$_COOKIE[session_name()].'; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly;');
}

session_write_close();
$result=curl_exec($ch);
```

The request works, but the session from the client is not used in it.

Did anyone know, how to request and use the same session?

Comment: I don't see a `session_start()`. Are you sure the session is really running?

Comment: yes a session is already running
(this code is part of a class in the project)

Comment: You can try to set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` and take look at the headers.

Comment: think, thats the important one Set-Cookie: sec_session_id=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0

info: sec_session_id --> session_name();

Comment: OUT: GET /project/fahrschule/api/v1/logout HTTP/1.1

Host: localhost

Accept: */*

Cookie: sec_session_id=58ci8gu4fd64r2352bs4g1n58o; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

Comment: You cannot forward sessions between independent machines.  Session cookies are not single-sign-on. If you want to share sessions between machines, you must use central storage for the session information. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php